# code going beyond footer in the website content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code snippet which works fine as shown below. Basically, when you click on first table, you will see another below, then click on the second one and you will see another below so on and so forth.

```js
var source = {
  localdata: [
    ["Test1", "2018-08-29 14:19:07", "2020-08-29 14:19:07", "Path1"],
    ["Test2", "2018-09-05 11:26:39", "2020-09-05 11:26:39", "Path2"],
    ["Test3", "2018-08-30 07:32:23", "2020-08-30 07:32:23", "Path3"],
    ["Test4", "2018-09-11 09:01:42", "2020-09-11 09:01:42", "Path4"],
    ["Test5", "2018-08-01 15:28:22", "2020-08-01 15:28:22", "Path5"],
    ["Test6", "2018-08-01 15:28:22", "2020-08-01 15:28:22", "Path6"],
    ["Test7", "2018-09-13 07:34:57", "2020-09-13 07:34:57", "Path7"]
  ],
  datafields: [{
      name: 'dataSetName',
      type: 'string',
      map: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'accessStartDate',
      type: 'date',
      map: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'accessEndDate',
      type: 'date',
      map: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'conceptPath',
      type: 'string',
      map: '3'
    }
  ],
  datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
  loadComplete: function(data) {},
  loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});

$("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid({

  source: dataAdapter,
  width: 381,
  height: '200',
  pageable: true,
  sortable: true,
  autoheight: true,
  columnsResize: true,
  theme: 'classic',
  columns: [{
      text: 'Data Set',
      datafield: 'dataSetName',
      width: 140

    },
    {
      text: 'Start Date',
      datafield: 'accessStartDate',
      width: 120,
      cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy'
    },
    {
      text: 'End Date',
      datafield: 'accessEndDate',
      width: 120,
      cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy'
    },
    {
      text: 'Concept Path',
      datafield: 'conceptPath',
      width: 50,
      hidden: true
    }
  ]

});

// Row Select Logic Starts Here
$("#main_downloader_grid").on("rowselect", function(e) {
  let data_set_name = $("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'dataSetName');

  console.log("Cell Value Test");
  console.log(data_set_name.value);


  let conceptPath = $("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'conceptPath');
  console.log("Concept Path Test");
  console.log(conceptPath.value);


  $('#commonWindow').remove();
  //$('.clickable').remove();
  $('.clickable').next('#testbutton').remove();
    $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();


  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.id = 'commonWindow';
  //elem.setAttribute('style', 'margin:500px 10px 20px 20px;');


  console.log(elem);



  let data = [{
      letter: '<b>People</b>'
    },
    {
      letter: '1) Detailed demographics data of all people'
    },
    {
      letter: '2) Attributes associated with all people'
    },
    {
      letter: '<b>Technology</b>'
    },
    {
      letter: '1) Computer details'
    },
    {
      letter: '2) Hardware Details'
    },
    {
      letter: '3) Software Details'
    },
    {
      letter: '<b>Company Details</b>'
    }
    /* {conceptpath: conceptPath.value } */
  ];
  let source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    datafields: [{
      name: 'letter',
      type: 'string'
    } /* ,{ name: 'conceptpath', type: 'string' } */ ]
  };
  let newDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

  $(elem).jqxGrid({
    source: newDataAdapter,
    width: 395,
    height:310,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Data set <b>' + data_set_name.value + '</b> selected, what data do you want to see?',
        datafield: 'letter'
        //width: 450
      }

    ]
  });
 
 document.body.appendChild(elem);
  // elem.id.style = "margin:50px 10px 20px 30px";
  elem.style.margin = "50px 10px 20px 50px";

$("#commonWindow").on("rowselect", handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  var $el = $("<div />", {
    class: "clickable",
    style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",
  })
  .on('click', handleClick)

  $el.jqxGrid({
    height: 270,width:520, pageable: true,source: dataAdapter, columns: [
      { text: 'Data Set Name', datafield: 'dataSetName', width: 200 },
      { text: 'Access Start Date', datafield: 'accessStartDate', width: 150,cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy' },
      { text: 'Access End Date', datafield: 'accessEndDate', width: 150,cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy' },
      { text: 'Concept Path', datafield: 'conceptPath', width: 100,hidden:true }
     
    ]
  });

  var $this = $(this), $parent = $(this).parent();

  if (e.type == 'rowselect') {
     $('.clickable').next('#testbutton').remove();
    $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();
  }

  var $button = $("<div id = 'testbutton'></div>").on('click', function (e) {
       $(".clickable").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', 'jqxGrid');
  });
  
 
  console.log($button);

  
  $button.jqxButton({ width: 100, height: 20});
    $button.html('Download Data');

  $el.after($button);

    $parent.append($el);
  $(this).off('click');
}


});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="main_downloader_grid" style="margin:50px 10px 20px 50px"></div>
  <div class="clickable" style="margin:50px 10px 20px 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

But when I plug-in the same code in the code snippet below. The first grid/table is shown at the right place. However, when I click on the first grid, the seond grid is shown below the footer. Could anyone explain me why it's going below footer?

I have put the relavent `div` as follows in the code below:

```
<div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <div class = "wrapper">
        <div id="main_downloader_grid" style="margin:50px 10px 20px 100px"></div>
        <div class ="clickable" style="margin:100px 10px 20px 20px;"></div>
      </div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
```

For your testing, the below code can be just copied and run locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" /> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css">
<!-- <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script> -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
/* Left column */
.leftcolumn {   
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

/* Right column */
.rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Fake image */
.fakeimg {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Add a card effect for articles */
.card {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Data Downloader</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" style="float:right">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <div class = "wrapper">
        <div id="main_downloader_grid" style="margin:50px 10px 20px 100px"></div>
        <div class ="clickable" style="margin:100px 10px 20px 20px;"></div>
      </div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:100px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
      <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
      <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
      <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Me</h3>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     (function () {

      var source = {
  localdata: [
    ["Test1", "2018-08-29 14:19:07", "2020-08-29 14:19:07", "Path1"],
    ["Test2", "2018-09-05 11:26:39", "2020-09-05 11:26:39", "Path2"],
    ["Test3", "2018-08-30 07:32:23", "2020-08-30 07:32:23", "Path3"],
    ["Test4", "2018-09-11 09:01:42", "2020-09-11 09:01:42", "Path4"],
    ["Test5", "2018-08-01 15:28:22", "2020-08-01 15:28:22", "Path5"],
    ["Test6", "2018-08-01 15:28:22", "2020-08-01 15:28:22", "Path6"],
    ["Test7", "2018-09-13 07:34:57", "2020-09-13 07:34:57", "Path7"]
  ],
  datafields: [{
      name: 'dataSetName',
      type: 'string',
      map: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'accessStartDate',
      type: 'date',
      map: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'accessEndDate',
      type: 'date',
      map: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'conceptPath',
      type: 'string',
      map: '3'
    }
  ],
  datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
  loadComplete: function(data) {},
  loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});

$("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid({

  source: dataAdapter,
  width: 381,
  height: '200',
  pageable: true,
  sortable: true,
  autoheight: true,
  columnsResize: true,
  theme: 'classic',
  columns: [{
      text: 'Data Set',
      datafield: 'dataSetName',
      width: 140

    },
    {
      text: 'Start Date',
      datafield: 'accessStartDate',
      width: 120,
      cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy'
    },
    {
      text: 'End Date',
      datafield: 'accessEndDate',
      width: 120,
      cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy'
    },
    {
      text: 'Concept Path',
      datafield: 'conceptPath',
      width: 50,
      hidden: true
    }
  ]

});

// Row Select Logic Starts Here
$("#main_downloader_grid").on("rowselect", function(e) {
  let data_set_name = $("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'dataSetName');

  console.log("Cell Value Test");
  console.log(data_set_name.value);


  let conceptPath = $("#main_downloader_grid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'conceptPath');
  console.log("Concept Path Test");
  console.log(conceptPath.value);


  $('#commonWindow').remove();
  //$('.clickable').remove();
  $('.clickable').next('#testbutton').remove();
    $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();


  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.id = 'commonWindow';
  //elem.setAttribute('style', 'margin:500px 10px 20px 20px;');


  console.log(elem);



  let data = [{
      letter: '<b>People</b>'
    },
    {
      letter: '1) Detailed demographics data of all people'
    },
    {
      letter: '2) Attributes associated with all people'
    },
    {
      letter: '<b>Technology</b>'
    },
    {
      letter: '1) Computer details'
    },
    {
      letter: '2) Hardware Details'
    },
    {
      letter: '3) Software Details'
    },
    {
      letter: '<b>Company Details</b>'
    }
    /* {conceptpath: conceptPath.value } */
  ];
  let source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    datafields: [{
      name: 'letter',
      type: 'string'
    } /* ,{ name: 'conceptpath', type: 'string' } */ ]
  };
  let newDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

  $(elem).jqxGrid({
    source: newDataAdapter,
    width: 395,
    height:310,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Data set <b>' + data_set_name.value + '</b> selected, what data do you want to see?',
        datafield: 'letter'
        //width: 450
      }

    ]
  });

 document.body.appendChild(elem);
  // elem.id.style = "margin:50px 10px 20px 30px";
  elem.style.margin = "50px 10px 20px 50px";

$("#commonWindow").on("rowselect", handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  var $el = $("<div />", {
    class: "clickable",
    style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 20px ",
  })
  .on('click', handleClick)

  $el.jqxGrid({
    height: 270,width:520, pageable: true,source: dataAdapter, columns: [
      { text: 'Data Set Name', datafield: 'dataSetName', width: 200 },
      { text: 'Access Start Date', datafield: 'accessStartDate', width: 150,cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy' },
      { text: 'Access End Date', datafield: 'accessEndDate', width: 150,cellsformat:'MM/dd/yyyy' },
      { text: 'Concept Path', datafield: 'conceptPath', width: 100,hidden:true }

    ]
  });

  var $this = $(this), $parent = $(this).parent();

  if (e.type == 'rowselect') {
     $('.clickable').next('#testbutton').remove();
    $('.clickable').slice(1).remove();
  }

  var $button = $("<div id = 'testbutton'></div>").on('click', function (e) {
       $(".clickable").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', 'jqxGrid');
  });


  console.log($button);


  $button.jqxButton({ width: 100, height: 20});
    $button.html('Download Data');

  $el.after($button);

    $parent.append($el);
  $(this).off('click');
}


});










})()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of `document.body.appendChild(elem);` in your `$("#main_downloader_grid").on("rowselect"` handler. appendChild is appending your new grid/table to the body's children where it becomes the last element. Since it's after the footer element, the new grid/table appears below the footer.

To fix this you'll want to find a way to place the new grid/table in the correct location. One possible approach is to use the [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) function. Something like `$(elem).insertAfter('#main_downloader_grid');`

Comment: Thanks. Using `$(elem).insertAfter('#main_downloader_grid');` worked for me instead of appending child.

Answer (score 0):

The table is being added below the footer because you are using `document.body.appendChild()` to add the new element. According to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) documentation, that's simply going to find the end of the provided node (`body` in this case) and append the new element there.

To display below the clicked element, you'll need to modify your code to append the child element to the clicked element's parent node.